# How to group by day and month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

Given a series like this

```
    Date
2005-01-01    128
2005-01-02     72
2005-01-03     67
2005-01-04     61
2005-01-05     33
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

for several years, how do I group all the January 1sts together, all the January 2nds, etc?

I'm actually trying to find the max for each day of the year across several years, so it does not have to be groupby. If there is an easier way to do this, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your index to datetime, then use `strftime` to get a date formatted string to group on:

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%b-%d'))['Date_Value'].max()
```

---

If there are no NaNs in your date string, you can slice as well. This returns strings of the format "MM-DD":

```
df.groupby(df.index.astype(str).str[5:])['Date_Value'].max()
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do I get ```NameError: name 'series' is not define``` for the line: ```series.groupby(dailymax.to_datetime(series.index).strftime('%b-%d')).max()```

Comment: @Dirk Series refers to your series. If maybe you want `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%b-%d'))['Date_Value'].max()`. Point being take this answer and mould it to fit your data and variable naming scheme.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use a pivot table:

Reset index and format date columns

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
df['year']=df['date'].dt.year
df['month']=df['date'].dt.month
df['day']=df['date'].dt.day
```

Pivot over the month and day columns:

```
df_grouped=df.pivot_table(index=('month','day'),values='Date',aggfunc='max')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why to not just keep it simple!

```
max_temp = dfall.groupby([(dfall.Date.dt.month),(dfall.Date.dt.day)])['Data_Value'].max()
```